# Python Communicating with Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I have this code

```
p.stdin.write('alloc ' + str(size) + '\n' + chr(0x1a))
p.stdin.flush()
stdout = p.stdout.readline()
```

The problem is that the script keeps hanging on the *readline()*

If I replace

```
p.stdin.flush()
```

with

```
p.stdin.close()
```

it works, but doesn't allow me to keep on communicating with the process after

What should I do to send the data to stdin and read reply from stdout and still be able to repeat that during the script?

Comment: The subprocess is probably using buffered output and unless you tell us what it is, we can't say if there's a way to make it unbuffered.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: It's a simple c program reading with
   fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);

Comment: what purpose does `chr(0x1a)` serve here?

Comment: and the subprocess is writing with fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", my_alloc(data));

Comment: I'm guessing your subprocess is waiting for EOF before sending its output.

Comment: As you can see I tried adding chr(0x1a) and also \x1a with no success, or should I do it differently?

Comment: EOF is not a readable character, it's a state associated with a file descriptor. You achieve it by closing the file. If for some reason you don't want to, you have to rewrite you client program to do its thing without waiting for EOF; perhaps it just waits until it has all the data it needs, or waits for a specific character sequence.

Comment: So pretty much, I can't simulate sending input to process the way Shell does in python?

Comment: @mOnAr wrong, you can do what you want, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and the subprocess is writing with fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", my_alloc(data));

Just as you did in the parent process, you'll have to `fflush(stdout)` after the `fprintf()` in the child because the stdio library will buffer the output (usually until there are BUFSIZ bytes waiting to write).

You might see that when you run the child from the shell it looks like it is emitting output on every newline. It is because the stdio library sets line buffering when attached to a terminal. It doesn't do this when attached to a pipe. See `isatty(3)` and `setbuf(3)` for details.

You're doing the right thing on the Python side, now you have to do the same on the C side of the pipe. The Python `readline` is blocking because the child has not yet sent anything up the pipe.